# Code crashes when writing text to Random Access File

Tags: c++, file-io, data-structures

The data file is just an integer, a string, another integer.
For Example:

```
20 Bob 550
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct RECORD
{
    int ID;
    string name;
    float balance;
};

void Display(char fname[])
{
    RECORD st;
    fstream f;
    f.open(fname, ios::in|ios::binary);
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
    for(int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
    {
        //read a record file from the RAF
        f.read((char*)&st, sizeof(st));
        cout<<st.ID<<'\t'<<st.name<<'\t'<<st.balance<<endl;
    }
    f.close();
}

int main()
{
    //initalize the RAF with dummy record 0, "nnn", 0.0
    fstream g;
    g.open("data.raf", ios::out|ios::binary);
    RECORD dummy={0, "nnn", 0.0};
    for(int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
    {
        g.write((char*)&dummy, sizeof(RECORD));
    }
    g.close();

    Display("data.raf");

    //copy text file into RAF
    fstream ftxt;
    fstream fraf;

    //open text file to read from
    ftxt.open("data.txt", ios::in);

    //open RAF to write
    fraf.open("data.raf", ios::out|ios::binary);

    for(int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
    {
        ftxt>>dummy.ID>>dummy.name>>dummy.balance;
        int byteOfSet = (dummy.ID/10-1)*sizeof(RECORD);

        //seekp to put (write)
        //seekg to get (read)
        fraf.seekp(byteOfSet, ios::beg);

        //beg   from beginning of file
        fraf.write((char*)&dummy, sizeof(RECORD));
    }

    //deposit 100 in ID #40
    int id;
    cout<<"Enter an ID number: ";
    cin>>id;
    fraf.open("data.raf", ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    int byteOfSet = (id/10-1)*sizeof(RECORD);
    fraf.seekg(byteOfSet, ios::beg);
    fraf.read((char*)&dummy, sizeof(RECORD));
    dummy.balance += 100;

    //put the updated record back into the same place
    fraf.seekp(byteOfSet, ios::beg);
    fraf.write((char*)&dummy, sizeof(RECORD));
    //fraf.close();

    ftxt.close();
    fraf.close();
    Display("data.raf");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs then just dies in the console... I have no idea what's wrong. I think it might have something to do with reacessing the RAF but that's just my guess.

Comment: How is `byteOfSet` a valid position to use with `seekp`?

Comment: You can't read/write `std::string` like plain old data.  You must serialize it.  If you want a fixed size record you're better off with a fixed size char array.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Where is he doing that?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Everywhere he uses `fstream::read` and `fstream::write`.  The `RECORD` struct has a `std::string` member.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You should add that as an answer. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja. I debugged it. that is the reason.